# Mozilla addons server API: "Duplicate add-on ID found"

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I try to write the script that will publish my extension to all stores, done with Chrome but stuck with Firefox. I was guided by [this documentation](http://addons-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html#uploading-without-an-id). I am able to upload to Mozilla store through the web page. I know that I can use existing [cli](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) but I do not want to introduce useless dependencies. [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) shows greenlight.

My code:

```
AMO_JWT_ISSUER=user:132XXXXX:XXX
AMO_SECRET=503084ad4069208a1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
JWT_HEADER_BASE64=`printf %s '{"alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT"}' | base64`

random() {
    dd if=/dev/urandom bs=20 count=1 2>/dev/null | openssl sha1
}
UNIXTIME=`date +%s`
PAYLOAD_JSON=$(python3 - <<EOF
import json
print(
    json.dumps({
        'iss': "${AMO_JWT_ISSUER}",
        'jti': "$(random)",
        'iat': $UNIXTIME,
        'exp': $(($UNIXTIME+99))
    })
)
EOF
)
JWT_PAYLOAD_BASE64=`printf %s $PAYLOAD_JSON | base64`
FOR_SIGN="$JWT_HEADER_BASE64.$JWT_PAYLOAD_BASE64"
JWT_SIGNATURE_BASE64=`printf %s $FOR_SIGN | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac $AMO_SECRET | base64`
JWT=$JWT_HEADER_BASE64.$JWT_PAYLOAD_BASE64.$JWT_SIGNATURE_BASE64

curl "https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/" \
    --form "upload=@$FIREFOX_FILEPATH_PROD" \
    --form "version=$VERSION" \
    -H "Authorization: JWT $JWT" \
    -v
```

Comment: Are you sure the version you are uploading doesn't exist already?

Comment: If I can upload through the official webpage - it is proves that version is not the same.